# Make a photo grid using CSS without IMG tags

Tags: css, html, grid, css-grid

I'm currenly messing around with a little project. I want to make a photo grid of 3x4 pictures in HTML5 (Without using Div's). I also want to add all pictures in the CSS. So no img tag in the HTML file.

The grid also needs to be responsive, when you scale it from desktop to tablet size it needs to become 2x4 photo grid

and the same with mobile, it needs to change to 1x4.

I've managed to make a 3x4 grid. I'm struggling with adding pictures in the CSS. I've tried the normal: background-image: url('picture.jpg'); but that doesn't work for some reason.

Also making everything scalable doesn't work. I've tried using media queries but to didn't work.

My code:

```css
#Product_grid{
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
.Product_img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.grid-item1{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
}
.grid-item2{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
}
.grid-item3{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
}
.grid-item4{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
}
.grid-item5{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
}
.grid-item6{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
}
.grid-item7{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
}
.grid-item8{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
}
.grid-item9{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
}
.grid-item10{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
}
.grid-item11{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
}
.grid-item12{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
  <article id="Product_grid">
    <section class="grid-item1"></section>
     <section class="grid-item2"></section>
     <section class="grid-item3"></section>
     <section class="grid-item4"></section>
     <section class="grid-item5"></section>
     <section class="grid-item6"></section>
     <section class="grid-item7"></section>
     <section class="grid-item8"></section>
     <section class="grid-item9"></section>
     <section class="grid-item10"></section>
     <section class="grid-item11"></section>
     <section class="grid-item12"></section>
</article>
```

Does someone have any idea how to make something like that?

kind regards,

Max

Comment: Phrased like this, it's too broad a question. Do you have any code already and does it need to be made responsive? Questions like that would be answerable. Otherwise it just sounds like you're asking people here to do your work for you. Let me say, your mention of "without using divs" sounds like you have put some thoughts in it already and you have decided on one method over others, or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: What about adding the Images into the Sections with an `<img>`-tag? Like creating the `<img>` with javasript and append it to each section?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to decide between a relative or an absolute path to the pictures you want to include.

E.g.: You have your index.html in your root-directory of the project and the images in the directory projectroot/img then you can use relative path's to the project-root,  absolute paths have to be from the Server/Machine-Root directory.

Try using this relative-path syntax:

`section{ background-image: url("../imagedirectory/image.jpg");`